# How to select a specific row from a table to edit or delete

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have implemented a booking system, part of the system  involves allowing users to modify or delete a booking. I am able to retrieve bookings from the database based on user's session and id which is displayed in a html table. I have been having trouble selecting a specific row from the html table to edit or delete a booking. I want to be able to select a specific row from the html table which i will then be able to edit or delete that record.

The code below retrieves the bookings and displays it in a table

**bookings.php**

> ```
> $sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM bookings1,users WHERE bookings1.userid = 
> users.userid  AND  users.username = '".$_SESSION['loggedInUser']."' ";
> ```

```
  $results = $mysqli->query($sqlquery);

if ($results->num_rows > 0) {
while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){

echo'<form method = "POST" action = "editmot.php" >';

 echo'<tr>';

  echo "<td>". $row["booking_id"]. "</td>";

   echo "<td>". $row["Type"]. "</td>";

     echo "<td>". $row["BookingDate"]. "</td>";

      echo "<td>". $row["Timeslot"]. "</td>";

        echo "<td>". $row["Manufacture"]. "</td>";

           echo "<td>". $row["Model"]. "</td>";

            echo "<td>". $row["RegistrationNo"]. "</td>";

           echo "<td><a href = 'editmot.php' id ='".$row['booking_id']."'> Edit </td>";

       echo "<td><a href = 'delete.php' id = '".$row['booking_id']."'> Remove </td>";

      echo '</tr>';

         echo '</form>';
```

Comment: This is a really original code indentation! Nice job!

Comment: @RohanRehman Have you written any code to edit/delete a row from the table or do you need help with that? (If you have written any code to edit/delete a row, please post it in your question as well).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "select a row from the html table", can you please clarify? @LorenzMeyer Don't be judgedmental, maybe this is a script that does exactly the same in whitespace as it does in php?

Comment: @iRuth  I need help with just editing/deleting a specific row from the html table in bookings.php file. I know i would need to use UPDATE and DELETE sql queries but i would need to select a specific row from the html table in order to run the query

Comment: I tried, it didn't work http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_%28programming_language%29

Comment: Sorry if my comment sounds judgmental. I just found it really funny.

Answer (score 0):

In the href attribute of the Edit Link, include the Booking_Id as a URL parameter. When the Edit page loads, pick up the booking_id from the URL parameter and fetch the other fields for edit. Like :

```
echo " <a href = 'editmot.php' . '?EditBookingId=' . $row['booking_id'] "
```

and then so on and so forth concatenate other things.

Your final href URL should look like : 
'`http://editmot.php?EditBookingId=24798`' or some such.

Answer (score 0):

use this code to edit or delete

```
<a href="samefile.php?action=update&id=$row['booking_id']">for edit</a>

<a href="samefile.php?action=delete&id=$row['booking_id']">for delete</a>

if(isset($_REQUEST['action']))
 if($_REQUEST['action']=="update")
  update query
else if($_REQUEST['action']=="delete")
delete query
```

Comment: yup this will do it if u are satisfied with this answer increase my point and select it as correct

Comment: After selecting one row, it should only display that row in the edit.php page, i only want to edit one record at a time

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the anchor tag, you could use a submit button and a hidden input field to hold the booking ID, since each booking detail (or row)  is in a separate form. You could use something like this in each booking row:

```
echo "<td><input name='edit' type='submit' value='Edit'>"
. "<input type='hidden' name='booking_id' value='".$row['booking_id']."'></td>";

echo "<td><input name='delete' type='submit' value='Remove'>"
. "<input type='hidden' name='booking_id' value='".$row['booking_id']."'></td>";
```

And then in `editmot.php`, process the delete or edit form action:

```
if (isset($_POST['edit'])) {
    // edit video here
}

if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    // delete video here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert the id in the url so you can get it with the [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) method in the edit or delete file.

So your anker needs to look something like:

```
<a href = 'delete.php?id=".$row['booking_id']."'>Delete</a>;
```

Now when a user go's to that url the url wil look something like:

```
localhost/delete.php?id=20
```

Now in your delete.php you can get the id with the $_GET method:

`$id = $_GET['id'];
 $qry = "DELETE FROM booking1 WHERE id=$id"; //this will delete the row where id is 20`

Comment: i have included the id in the url but it is not showing the id in the url

Comment: echo "<td><a href = 'delete.php?id=".$row['booking_id']."'> Remove </td>";   <-- copy paste that. tested it, should work

Comment: yeah its getting the id in the url, thank you for the help i appreciate it